# Getting unwanted delimiter after last column in database to csv

Tags: csv, delimiter

This is the code I am using in Visual Basic:

```
Private Sub ToolStripButton1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ToolStripButton1.Click
    Call data_to_txt(Database1DataSet.entries, "‪glossary.cvs", False, "|")
End Sub

Private Sub data_to_txt(ByVal dt As DataTable, ByVal filename As String, ByVal header As Boolean, ByVal delimiter As String)
    'New instance of a streamwriter
    Dim sw As IO.StreamWriter = New IO.StreamWriter(filename, False)

    'Exit if there's nothing in the textfile
    If dt.Columns.Count < 0 OrElse dt.Rows.Count < 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If header Then
        For Each col As DataColumn In dt.Columns
            'Write the header
            sw.Write(col.Caption & delimiter)
        Next
        'Start a new line
        sw.WriteLine()
    End If

    'Loop through all the cells in the datatable
    For row As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
        For col As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1

            sw.Write(dt.Rows(row).Item(col).ToString & delimiter)
        Next
        'At the final column, start a new line
        sw.Write(Environment.NewLine)
    Next

    'Close the streamwriter
    sw.Close()
End Sub
```

And I get: 
1|whatever|whatever|

When it should be:
1|whatever|whatever

(ie. no final unwanted delimiter)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the logic with this code block:

```
'Loop through all the cells in the datatable
For row As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
    For col As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1

        sw.Write(dt.Rows(row).Item(col).ToString & delimiter)
    Next
    'At the final column, start a new line
    sw.Write(Environment.NewLine)
Next
```

The `delimiter` is always written out after each row element.  You need to alter the logic so that the `delimiter` never follows a row element.

One way to solve this is to set a flag to `true` at the beginning of each row.  When that flag is set to true then the row element is written as:

```
sw.Write(dt.Rows(row).Item(col).ToString)
flag = false
```

When the flag is false, then all other elements should be written as:

```
sw.Write(delimiter & dt.Rows(row).Item(col).ToString)
```

This algorithm will assure that a delimiter never appears at the end of a line, and will only separate row elements if there is more than one of them.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm an absolute beginner...I found the code but I don't know how to modify it to set flag to true or false...